# Poulet numbers of the form $3p$, where $p$ is a palindrome

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, conjectures, pseudoprimes

A Poulet-number is a composite number $N$ satisfying $$2^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$$ A palindrome is a positive integer with a digit string in base $10$ which remains the same if it is written down backwards.

If $3p$ is a Poulet-number and $p$ a palindrome , it seems that $p$ must begin (and therefore end) with digit $7$. The examples upto $p=10^{18}$ are :

```
23001 7667 [11, 1; 17, 1; 41, 1]
212421 70807 [11, 1; 41, 1; 157, 1]
23054601 7684867 [17, 1; 251, 1; 1801, 1]
235201461 78400487 [11, 1; 41, 1; 131, 1; 1327, 1]
```

> Why is $p$ always of the form $7...7$ ?

> Why is $p$ divisible by $41$ , if it is divisible by $11$ ?

Any counter-example?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Since I suspect quite a few people, even those knowledgeable about number theory, may not recognize the phrase "Poulet numbers", I recommend you define that term rather than having them need to look it up. In particular, as stated in Wikipedia's [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) article, there's "Pseudoprimes to base $2$ are sometimes called Sarrus numbers, after P. F. Sarrus who discovered that $341$ has this property, Poulet numbers, after P. Poulet who made a table of such numbers, or Fermatians (sequence A001567 in the OEIS)."

Comment: @JohnOmielan they are so famous!

Comment: There are on the order of $10^{d/2}$ numbers with $d$ digits that are $3$ times a palindrome.  It seems (from looking at the b-file at sequence A001567) the number of Poulet numbers with $d$ digits grows like $k^d$ for some $k < \sqrt{10}$.  So one should perhaps expect there to be only finitely many Poulet numbers that are $3$ times a palindrome, and your examples may be the only ones.

Comment: You have successfully found the only examples with $3p \leq 2^{64}$.